# Check if bit has toggled in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, toggle

I am working on bitwise manipulation (in C) and I wanted to know how to check if a bit has toggled between a previous value and the new value.

```
Example :
    oldValue = 0x0FF //0000 1111 1111 in binary
    newValue = 0x100 //0001 0000 0000 in binary
```

In this example I want to check if the bit8 (9th bit) has toggled from 0 to 1.

I know that if I want to know if a bit is set, is can use :

```
value & (1 << 8)
```

So, is this correct ? :

```
if( (oldValue & (1 << 8)) == (newValue & (1 << 8)) ) //return 0 if toggled
```

Comment: "Bit 8" is not "7th bit", at least not as you've shown. It's the other way around ("bit 7" is "8th bit"). You're talking about bit 8, the 9th bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

First, use `XOR` to find *all* bits that have toggled:

```
int allToggled = oldValue ^ newValue;
```

Then mask the bit that you want to keep - for example, by shifting `allToggled` to the right, so that the target bit is at position zero, and mask with `1`:

```
int targetBitToggled = (allToggled >> 8) & 1;
```

Now combine these two expressions into a single condition:

```
if ((oldValue ^ newValue) & (1 << 8)) {
    // ... bit at position 8 has toggled
}
```

Note that instead of shifting the `XOR`-ed values right I shifted the bit mask left.

Comment: Perfectly explained ! Thank you :)

Answer (score -2):

Use an XOR, it will be 1 for every bit that is different between `oldValue` and `newValue`:

```
   if((oldValue ^ newValue) == (1 << 7))
      // 8th bit has toggled
```

Comment: Not what the OP wants. This checks if the 8-th bit was the *only* bit that toggled.